# Java code quality trending and stats (LOC, methods, etc.) trending

Tags: java, sonarqube, cruisecontrol, emma

I've recently integrated Junit and Emma into CruiseControl (CC) so it creates nice reports per build. I'd like to see some trending graphs based on some of the info Emma gives like the coverage % numbers and the summary:

```
OVERALL STATS SUMMARY  
total packages: 54  
total executable files: 1001  
total classes:  1133  
total methods:  11814  
total executable lines: 112428
```

Ideally, we could have one page that has (google charts?) graphs of each that gets updated every build. I googled a bit and it looks like there is a jenkins plugin that might do this, but I didn't see anything similar for CC. I'm also planning on getting Sonar up and running in CC too so maybe Sonar does this?

I could certainly write my own code to create trending graphs (doesn't seem too hard to parse the emma output and create a page of graphs) but I would rather not re-invent the wheel.

Ah - just found this "Another approach would be to use the Sonar plugin for Hudson to maintain trending of coverage over time" in [Can my build stipulate that my code coverage never get worse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389680/can-my-build-stipulate-that-my-code-coverage-never-get-worse)
I could install Hudson and use that instead of CC but would rather not if I don't have to.

So - my question - what's the easiest way to get trending coverage/stats on my java code (hopefully within CruiseControl)?

Comment: Without wanting to start a religious war, I recommend giving Hudson/Jenkins a try. They are ridiculously easy to get started, and if you don't have a heavily customized CruiseControl build, will probably take you no longer than 30 minutes to set up.

Comment: Yeah - I used Hudson/Jenkins at my last job. I didn't set it up but did use (and like) it. I've only been at this job a few months and not willing (yet) to convince them to install H/J just to get trending (which was my idea, not management's). If there is no (relatively easy) solution to get this in CC, I may look at H/J down the road.

Comment: I really like Sonar, precisely because of its ability to show trending graphs.  If your build is Maven-based, you can invoke a Sonar plugin target in Cruise Control.  I get why you don't want to upset the continuous integration apple cart, but I think your life will be easier if you bite the bullet and convert to Hudson or Jenkins.

Comment: Our build is not Maven-based. But... I just installed Jenkins locally and in less than 10 minutes I had it building our code, running junit, and building our war. Jenkins is looking better and better. Plus it can easily do lots of other cron-type jobs for us. I have an email drafted to send to the PHBs to see if I can get us moved to Jenkins :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Sonar Hudson/Jenkins plugin is definitely not mandatory to be able to run Sonar analyses. You can invoke Sonar from any tool (command line, CI tool like CC, ...etc.).

You just need to provide Sonar with some information, may it be in the POM if you're using Maven, in a build.xml file if you're using Ant, in a "sonar-project.properties" file if you plan to use the simple Sonar Runner, or just by passing properties if you will be using Jenkins/Hudson.

Check out [our documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Installing+Sonar) on the different ways to invoke Sonar to know more about all this.

Comment: Ah - so Sonar can provide trending regardless of where it's run from? I know I can run Sonar, I just didn't realize it did trending automatically. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, exactly! :-) Everything is centralized in a database and you browse the results from a web application